# Android How to display only certain items in list view from the same array?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I have been following several tutorials that have made me succeed in getting information from my database from my website to my app, then I can display it in a list view, but what I want to do is not show the complete list, I want to have a couple of buttons that let me display only the data that meets certain criteria, like bottom 1 only show list items that medio=Periodicos and button 2 show items that medio=Radios here is the code I'm using

in my main Activity

```
FancyAdapter aa = null;
static ArrayList<String> resultRow;

//after onCreate
//this button I'm usin now but I'm getting the hole list!
Button periodicos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPeriodicos);
            periodicos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                weballamar = "http://www.mysite.com/mydbjsonstring.php";
                webcall();
            }});

//webcall gets the info from the internet and displays the list
public void webcall(){
    ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistView);
    aa = new FancyAdapter();
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(onPeriodicosListClick);
    myListView.setAdapter(aa);
    PeriodicosListLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    webLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    try {
        String result = "";
                    try {
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(weballamar);
                        // httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream webs = entity.getContent();
                        // convert response to string
                        try {
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            String line = null;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                            webs.close();

                            result = sb.toString();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                    }

                    // parse json data
                    try {
                        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            webResult resultRow = new webResult();
                            resultRow._id = json_data.getString("id");
                            resultRow.Name = json_data.getString("Id_Nombre");
                            resultRow.Medio = json_data.getString("Medio");
                            resultRow.Pais = json_data.getString("Pais");
                            resultRow.Estado = json_data.getString("Estado");
                            resultRow.Ciudad = json_data.getString("Ciudad");
                            resultRow.website = json_data.getString("website");
                            resultRow.Url = json_data.getString("Url");
                            resultRow.Url2 = json_data.getString("Url2");
                            resultRow.InfAnex = json_data.getString("InfAnex");
                            arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // this is the line of code that sends a real error message to the
        // log
        Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());
        // this is the line that prints out the location in
        // the code where the error occurred.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<webResult> {
    FancyAdapter() {
        super(mainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfWebData);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(arrayOfWebData.get(position));

        return (convertView);
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    public TextView name = null;
    public TextView estado = null;
    public TextView ciudad = null;
    ViewHolder(View row) {
        name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.periodicoName);
        estado = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.periodicoEstado);
        ciudad = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.periodicoCiudad);
    }

    void populateFrom(webResult r) {
        name.setText(r.Name);
        estado.setText(r.Estado);
        ciudad.setText(r.Ciudad);
    }
}
```

as you can see I' displaying the complete list of columns of names estates and cities in my list view, but that list contains items that in the medio column are either periodic or radio, so how can I make my adapter differentiate and choose to display only the ones witch medio=periodico, from there I might be able to do the opposite to pick the medio=radio
Tahnks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't test this code, but here is something that might work

1) Create another list that holds only the filtered items

```
public ... ArrayList<webResult> FilteredArrayOfWebItems;
```

2) Create a method in your adapter that lets you set the "type" (periodico or radio)
    String type;

```
public void SetType(String type)
{ 
     /* Maybe something like this */
     //Clear the FilteredArrayOfWebItems first. Not on eclipse, at the moment, but I suspect FilteredArrayOfWebItems.clear() might be call you need

    for(JSONObject currentItem: arrayOfWebItems)
    {
        //Check if the Medio property of the current item matches the typ
        if(currentItem.Medio.equals(type))
        {
            //Add it to the Filtered list
            FilteredArrayOfWebItems.add(currentItem);

        }
     }
```

}

3) You may need to override the getCount() method to get the count of the filtered items, instead of the full list

4) In your get View, read the information from the filtered list

```
holder.populateFrom(FilteredArrayOfWebItems.get(position));
```

5) From your main method call SetType whenever you want to change the filter

6) From the main method, call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter after you've changed the filter

Comment: This sounds like what I'm looking for, but how can I make the code for the steType()? I mean how can I make it pull only the items that match my criteria

Comment: I added an implementation to the SetType(...) method. You should probably use it as pseduo-code to construct your real method, but hopefully it gives you an idea of what to do.

Comment: This got it done!, Thanks Gophermofur!, I just added the to FilteredArrayOfWebItems to the adpter too.

Answer (score 0):

Create one xml in layout folder    **fake.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);



    /*****  add this code in your getView method() ********/
      if(position ==3)
      {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fake, null);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            returns convertview;
       }
     /*****  add this code in your getView method() ********/



    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.populateFrom(arrayOfWebData.get(position));

    return (convertView);
}
```

Comment: no not yet, I don't have a computer right now, but I will give it a try.

Comment: can you explain how it works?, where does it filter the list? thanks

Comment: It is where it saids if(position ==3) right?, so shouldn't it be if(position =="Periodicos") or if(position =="Radio")?

Comment: @zvzej: It will skip particular data. It inflates FAKE layout so you can get output what u want.
Position is an integer.
I have just give u for exampel you want to skip 3rd row.
.... It works just try out tell me if u find any problem

Answer (score 0):

In customized list activity, remove the elements that u don't need and store the list into some temp list and pass that temp list to your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

it's enough if you do this:

```
if(position >2)
  {
        return convertView;
   }
```

It will not show more than 3 results (0,1,2)